# Eclipse Javascript -- how to order multiple files?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I'm using "*Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers.*"

I split my Javascript code into several script files.
I declare an object or a class-constructor in one file and the code assistent knows the object or the class in all the other files.
But it doesn't know about the content of the object. It seems the editor doesn't know the order in which the single files are to be loaded.

Is there a way to say to the Editor the order in which the files are to be loaded by the interpreter?

Here is a simple example.
I split my javascript code in 2 'modules'.
I define the object `ob` in module1.js

```
// module1.js
var ob = { a: 'aaa' };
```

In module2.js, the code assistent knows about object `ob` existence, but it doesn't know about the content of the object (`ob.a`).

Answer (score 1):

The "order of the files" does not matter. The code asstistent knows about `ob` after all. The problem is that only prototypes seem to have a full project wide support. So if you had

```
function MyObj() {}

MyObj.prototype = {
  aFunction: function() {
  ...
```

and in another file

```
var obj = new MyObj();
```

then, when you type `obj.`, `aFunction` is suggested.

If you only write JavaScript and maybe HTML / CSS then I recommend using another IDE. Netbeans supports what you want, some people seem to be happy with Aptana, to name two.

If you really want or have to use Eclipse then you could look out for a plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I installed NetBeans and I'm trying but it's even worse at the moment. It seems each js file is alone by itself.

Comment: That's strange. It works perfectly for me. Which version and bundle did you install?

Comment: NetBeans has weird behaviours too. I can finally see the object properties in the other files, but when I add a class constructor as a property of a namespacing object, there comes the mess. The properties of the class are seen as properties of the namespace.

Comment: It's not perfect, I know. It's still better than Eclipse when It comes to JavaScript. And to be honest: There are situations where it's almost impossible to get autocompletion out of the box. Welcome to the world of JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way vjet js IDE handles this http://wiki.eclipse.org/VJET/JS_code_assist_and_validation_for_two_or_more_js_files

Comment: I will try, but what I can see in the example, Eclipse already does. The question is if I will see the content of a 'simple' object, the static properties and members of a class...

Comment: I've seen, vjet is something different, I was thinking it could assist Eclipse Javascript DT, but it's a different tool.